# Разрешить субдомену встраиваться в фрейм

Tags: .htaccess

Есть сайт site.com в котором во фрейме открывается сайт a.site.com
Выдает ошибку

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Как это решить?
Нашел решение `Content-Security-Policy` пишу в .htaccess на субдомене

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Content-Security-Policy "child-src https://a.site.com"
</IfModule>
```

Но это не работает
Кто знает в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Встраивание iframe не запрещено, он у вас встраивается. Запрещён доступ из iframe с одним происхождением в iframe с другим. Нужны заголовки [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Есть статья на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/owasp/blog/337146/)